# Application cannot compile after I created mime-type.validator.ts 1 post by 1 author

Tags: angular, mime-types

I created the file mime-type.validator.ts.

I am yet to use this file in my application. However, the file exists in my project.

Now, my application does not compile. I am getting the error as follows.

Failed to compile.
Source file not found: '/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/Paikari/pConfMan/src/app/mime-type.validator.ts'.

Earlier, I had created a .ts file as I felt I should have that. However, later I realised that I could add that function in one of my existing .ts files. So, I deleted that new .ts file. My application would not compile after that.

To solve this, I created an empty .ts file with the same name as earlier and then the application was compiling.

Request if you can provide me the solution.

Thanks and Regards,
Partha

[See the file exists in the application in the correct path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBbTk.jpg)

[The error as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKqyS.jpg)

Comment: Restart your local server and shut down your ide entirely. Then open up and try to compile again, does the error still happen?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are calling that file somewhere in your app. 
Since you are using VSC i would just search the whole project-tree for 'mime-type.validator.ts' using the search function:

[image]

and then browse through the files and delete the references in whatever files they are present. That should solve your problem.. ;)